# Silent dowload using jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, download, silent

How can I make an HTML page and have it do a **silent**(!!) download of a file to a path on my Windows machine?

I want that, as soon as my Windows computer goes to this web page, it to automatically download the file of my choosing  from my server to `C:\Program Files`, for example. This would be all on my private network.

So my aim is, if I have a file called `target` on the  server, to download it to `C:\Program Files`, all through this webpage.

How can I accomplish this?

I have something like the following in mind:

```
<a href="#">Download Here</a>

 $('a').click... //Some jquery to download the file
```

I'd prefer to do it just with HTML and Javascript, since I'm not so fluent in jQuery.

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: This would be a massive security failure from the browser's part if it was possible. Therefore it isn't.

Comment: by default download, need to be accepted by user

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.  The answer is also NO.

Comment: even if its on your own network?

Comment: You can write your own webbrowser (windows program).  That webbrowser would have the functionality you want, by default.  Any exe does.  File access for the webbrowser is only restricted, on purpose, for security reasons.  To stop people like you (no offence :) ) from doing the things you ask.  I once made a C++ program with webbrowser component (it's a standard buttun in Visual Studio) to do asynchronous image upload.